# Data Factory concatenate two arrays

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-data-factory

I have two arrays (job_1 and job_2) which I need to concatenate in one array:

[[image]

In DataFlow, I use the code:

```
union([job_1],[job_2])
```

I need to have everything in one array this way:

```
["1428526", "1425403","1425696","1425126","1424631","1381348"]
```

NOT THIS WAY

```
["1428526"]["1425403","1425696","1425126","1424631","1381348"]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `', [] "'` from values of two columns

   ```
   split(replace(replace(replace(job_ids, '"', ''), ']', ''), '[', ''),',')
   ```
2. Add two columns together

   ```
   new = job_1 + job_2
   ```
3. Convert new column to string

   ```
   toString(new)
   ```